# Short form of comparison in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison

is there a short form for something like this:

```
if (someBooleanObject == null || someBooleanObject == false)
```

I think about something like this, if you get the idea:

```
if (someBooleanObject == (null || false))
```

or to example, is there a short form for something like this:

```
if (someInt == 1 || someInt == 2)
```

to something like this?

```
if (someInt == (1 || 2))
```

Comment: No, no such shorter form exists.

Comment: if (!someBooleanObject)

Comment: @nhgrif: that will cause a NullPointerException if someBooleanObject is null.

Comment: And that's why it's a comment. I didn't know, but that'll work in some other languages just fine.

Comment: Well inorder to avoid the null you can always assign an initial values to a variable... This would help you atleast eliminate the null condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing resembling any of these, but if you have a long enough list of of objects to check against, you can put them in a list and use [`List.contains(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
List<Integer> checks = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
if (checks.contains(someInt) {
    // ...
}
```

This will not be more concise for small lists, but may sometimes be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not and why are you trying to find a short from of it? because it will just gonna check one of them.

Comment: It would be really useful for making constructions like this: if (someInt is neither 1 nor 2 nor 3)